# Fit custom view's frame to image drawn in drawRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect, uibezierpath

I am drawing a custom shape (pentagon) in drawRect of my custom UIView subclass:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    // Set the starting point of the shape.
    [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 0.0)];

    // Draw the lines.
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200.0, 40.0)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(160, 140)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(40.0, 140)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 40.0)];
    [aPath closePath];

    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];

    [aPath fill];
    [aPath stroke];
}
```

When I add the custom drawing to my viewcontroller with:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    PentagonView *pentagonView = [[PentagonView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
    [self.view addSubview:pentagonView];
}
```

It ends up looking like:

[image]

Obviously I know I'm setting my frame to be 300 width/height, but is there a way to do a "size to fit" content on the view's frame after the contents have been drawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are kind of doing this backwards. The `drawRect:` method should draw its contents to fill its current bounds. In other words, don't hardcode any specific coordinates in `drawRect:`. Calculate them properly based on the current bounds.

If you want the custom view to have a certain size, override the custom view's `sizeToFit:` method and return the appropriate size.

This way, when client code calls the custom view's `sizeToFit` method, the view will be sized based on the results of `sizeToFit:`. Then the `drawRect:` method will be called and it will draw to fill that size.

Comment: Thanks, I set the drawRect drawing to draw based on the bounds of the view like you said. That works great. One question though - Why override/call sizeToFit to specify a certain size if I can do the same thing by initWithFrame when I create the custom uiview object?

Comment: It depends on what your goal is. If you want the custom view to dictate what size it can be, then override `sizeThatFits:`. If you want users of the custom view to specify the size, then don't. Given what you stated in your comment, you do not want to override `sizeThatFits:`.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep a reference to your `UIBezierPath`, you can call `bounds` on it to get the bounding rectangle. Override `sizeToFit` to use it:

```
- (void)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
  CGSize newSize = CGSizeZero;
  newSize.width = MIN(size.width, CGRectGetMaxX(self.path.bounds));
  newSize.height = MIN(size.height, CGRectGetMaxY(self.path.bounds));
  return newSize;
}
```

Comment: The proper approach is to override `sizeThatFits:` to return the proper size instead of overriding `sizeToFit`. This is stated in the docs for `UIView sizeToFit`.